# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'permission_id' cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working on user subscriptions plans so therefor I was working on user roles and permissions
I am trying to insert user roles and their permissions into a pivot table but when I try to submit my form it shows me this error

// This is my Model Files

//Permission Model

```
class Permission extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'mq_info_permissions';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name_arabic',
        'name_english',
    ];

    public function roles(){
        $this->belongsToMany(Roles::class,'mq_info_permission_roles', 'permission_id','role_id');
    }
}
```

// Role Model

```
class Roles extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'mq_info_roles';
    protected $fillable = ['name_arabic','name_english','status'];


    public function permissions(){
       return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class,'mq_info_permission_roles', 'permission_id','role_id');
       
    }
}
```

// This is my controller file

```
public function store(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name_arabic'=>'required|string',
            'name_english'=>'required|string',
        ]);
        $roles  = new Roles();
        $roles->name_arabic = $request->input('name_arabic');
        $roles->name_english = $request->input('name_english');
        $roles->status = $request->input('status') == TRUE?'1':'0';

        // $roles->save();
        // dd($roles->name_english);
        

        $listOfPermissions = explode(',', $request->roles_permissions);

        foreach($listOfPermissions as $permission){
            $permissions = new Permission();
            $permissions->name_english = $permission;
            $permissions->save();

            $roles->permissions()->attach($permissions->id);
            $roles->save();

        }

        return redirect()->route('Roles.index')->with('status','Role Added Successfully');
     
    }
```

// This is my pivot table migration

```
Schema::create('mq_info_permission_roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('permission_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');

            $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('mq_info_permissions')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('mq_info_roles')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->primary(['permission_id','role_id']);
            
        });
```

Can you please tell me what is the mistake I am making.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really code in Laravel but hope this helps:

As the error described in your title says you are trying to store a row in your table without passing the permission_id value, which is required because of an integrity constraint.

So be sure to either pass a permission_id value or allow the permission_id column to be null on the table you are trying to insert.